# regex into elements into array

Tags: html, arrays, regex, image

I'm using `/<img\s+[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>/g` to search HTML for `<img>` tags. It is working. However, its passing into an array as 1 element when there are multiple tags. Is there a way to pass EACH tag into the array as a unique element? I.e.

var arr = [img TAG1, img TAG2, img TAG3 ,img TAG4]

For now it does this and looks like each tag is it's own element but it's not. Here is an output.

```
var list = arr[0];
```

**Output of script:**

```
list =
    <'img' src="/RightAnswers/WB FAQs/Mail &amp; Collaboration/090101028112912.jpg" alt="Inline Image" />,
    <'img' src="/RightAnswers/WB FAQs/Mail &amp; Collaboration/090101028113127.jpg" alt="Inline Image" />,
    <'img' src="/RightAnswers/WB FAQs/Mail &amp; Collaboration/090101028113955.jpg" alt="Inline Image" />,
    <'img 'src="/RightAnswers/WB FAQs/Mail &amp; Collaboration/090101028114034.jpg" alt="Inline Image" />
    <'img' src="/RightAnswers/WB FAQs/Mail &amp; Collaboration/090101028114105.jpg" alt="Inline Image" />,
    <'img' src="/RightAnswers/WB FAQs/Mail &amp; Collaboration/090101028114345.jpg" alt="Inline Image" />
```

***Note- I had to wrap the `<img>` tags in a quote ('img') to submit this question. They are NOT present in the actual output.***

```
var list = arr[1];
```

**Output of script:**

```
list=undefined
```

I have seen that regex is not the best tool for parsing HTML, I need to do this once as part of an import into ServiceNow so I don't really have access to parsing tools. Unless there is something I can run a CSV through to grab JUST the file name from the `<img>`tags.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use javascript to collect all img elements instead of regex?

Like this:

```js
var imgCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
console.log(imgCollection);
```

```html
<div id="just-a-div"><p>random paragraph</p></div>

<img src="/RightAnswers/WB FAQs/Mail &amp; Collaboration/090101028112912.jpg" alt="Inline Image" />
<img src="/RightAnswers/WB FAQs/Mail &amp; Collaboration/090101028113127.jpg" alt="Inline Image" />
<img src="/RightAnswers/WB FAQs/Mail &amp; Collaboration/090101028113955.jpg" alt="Inline Image" />
<div></div>
```

Comment: I don't have access to the DOM, from ServiceNow.

Comment: Can you add the code your are using to match the HTML string with the regex pattern? Because when I run your regex it works just fine...